# Finding Limits And Continuity

Tags: limits

What is the limit of the function $$\lim_{x \to 0}|x|^{cos x}$$, and how to deal with continuity of such functions?

Comment: You meant $|x|\cos x$??

Comment: @Ahlfkushevich: more probably $|x|^{\cos x}$.

Comment: Definitely zero.

Comment: "how to deal with continuity of such functions ? ": please explain the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For small enough $|x|$ we have$${1\over 2}\le {\cos x}\le 1\implies |x|\le|x|^{\cos x}\le \sqrt {|x|}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\cos x$ tends to $1$ and the limit is essentially that of $|x|$, i.e. $0$. There is no particular difficulty.

The function is continuous everywhere.